# Traducción de una frase de un libro difícil

Tags: traducción, literatura

He encontrado esta frase en un libro que estoy leyendo -- domino castellano bastante bien, pero no puedo entender, excepto en un sentido amplio, lo que dice.  Aunque falta el contexto, ¿podríais proporcionar una traducción?  Google translate ha fallado completamente.  Os lo agradecería.

> Por eso mismo -- por ser la razón más fuerte, por necesitarle de
>   manera imperiosa e inexorable -- ni podía llegarse hasta allí ni para
>   ser consecuente consigo misma se decidiría a hacer uso de pretextos
>   para cruzarse con él, yendo de paso.

Comment: ¿De qué libro se trata? ¿Qué intentaste? Dicho lo cual, es ciertamente una frase complicada, por los incisos que hace y por el estilo algo recargado.

Comment: Parece que falta alguna puntuación.

Comment: Traduccion o interpretación ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumo que el problema está después de "inexorable". La primera parte, creo, es sencilla: comienza diciendo "Por eso mismo" y luego aclara entre guiones qué es "eso mismo", aunque hay una posible ambigüedad que debe resolver el contexto cuando dice "por ser la razón más fuerte": ¿significa "por ser (algo mencionado antes) la razón más fuerte", o bien "porque la razón (=la racionalidad, la facultad de razonar) era más fuerte"?

El resto queda:

> *...ni podía llegarse hasta allí ni para ser consecuente consigo misma se decidiría a hacer uso de pretextos para cruzarse con él, yendo de paso.*

Aquí hay dos proposiciones negativas coordinadas en una estructura *ni... ni...* que seguramente conoces. El problema es que la frase es una *[garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence)*. Donde dice "ni para ser consecuente consigo misma se decidiría...", debe leerse:

> "... ni (para ser consecuente consigo misma) se decidiría..."

es decir:

> "... ni estaba dispuesta a decidir, porque quería ser consecuente consigo misma..."

O sea, "para ser consecuente consigo misma" es una aclaración de "ni se decidiría" (y de hecho podrías quitar esta aclaración y la frase continúa siendo gramaticalmente correcta).

El problema es que, debido al orden poco habitual de las estructuras en la frase, quien la lee puede sentirse tentado a un *parsing* incorrecto:

> "... ni podía llegarse hasta allí (ni para ser consecuente consigo misma)..."

Es decir: hasta el momento anterior a cuando se llega a "se decidiría", el lector puede estar interpretando la frase como

> "...ni podía llegarse hasta allí **ni siquiera** para ser consecuente consigo misma..."

Cuando llegamos a "se decidiría" esta forma de leer la frase se vuelve imposible y hay que volver atrás, de manera similar a lo que ocurre con ejemplos típicos de *garden-path sentences* en inglés como *"The horse raced past the barn fell"*. Esto me ocurrió a mí, de hecho, y quizá sea el problema que estás encontrándote.

Comment: @pablodf76, Sí, eso era el problema.  ¡Gracias!